# C# WPF Thread Monitoring (If All Created Threads has Ended)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm a bit new to C# and WPF with my Project. Small picture of what i'm doing in the past. I wrote a Programm that does a backup of my MS SQL Databases. The idea was, to start every backup process in it's own process thread. That worked perfect! I start the process and thread by using:

```
...
string db_name = Convert.ToString(dataReader.GetValue(0));
var t = new Thread(() => BackupProcess(ServerName, SQLinstance, BackupPath, db_name));
t.Start();
```

Now, when all comes to an end, i would like to Monitor like "If the last thread comes to end, than do something like XY"
What is the best way do this?
THX for answering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there is no reason to directly deal with threads now. It is fairly easy to do with [Task Parallel Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [async-await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx).

You start number of Tasks, keep the reference of tasks, and wait/await it when needed.

```
Task backupTask = Task.Run(() => BackupProcess(ServerName, SQLinstance, BackupPath, db_name));
Task someOtherTask = Task.Run(() => SomeOtherWork(anyParameter));
...
//Later at some point    
await Task.WhenAll(new []{backupTask, someOtherTask });
//At this point all tasks has been completed
//Do whatever you need to execute after all tasks finished
```

Note: `BackupProcess` can be made asynchronous if you use [asynchronous API of your data provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh211418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) without the use of `Task.Run` which makes a ThreadPool thread to wait there.

If you still wanted to go with Thread approach(which you shouldn't), you can use `CountDownEvent` for synchronization or `Thread.Join` on all the started threads.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the TPL and the ContinueWith. It's very elegant and should match your requirements.

```
Action<string> action =
            (str) =>
                Console.WriteLine("Task={0}, str={1}, Thread={2}", Task.CurrentId, str, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

// Creating a sequence of action tasks (that return no result).
Console.WriteLine("Creating a sequence of action tasks (that return no result)");
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action("alpha"))
            .ContinueWith(antecendent => action("beta"))        // Antecedent data is ignored
            .ContinueWith(antecendent => action("gamma"))
            .Wait();
```

from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd321405(v=vs.110).aspx

ContinueWith() also can help you handle exceptions that occured while executing the task.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i do not really understand the way it goes. As you can see, i'm going to start a new Task inside my Loop at Point: "while (dataReader.Read())". As much databases as i have in my Server, the Loop will repeat. I don't know how many DB's i will have in the next time. At the end, when ALL Tasks are finished, i would like to go to the "DoSomething" Method. Is there anybody who can tell me the way it goes. It makes me crazy (this stuff). :-)

```
    private async void ReadDatabase()
    {
        string errorMSG01 = "...";
        string errorMSG02 = "...";
        string captionMSG = "...

        string BackupPath = txtBakPath.Text;
        string ServerName = txtSqlServer.Text;
        string SQLinstance = cmbSqlInst.SelectedItem.ToString();

        MessageBoxButtons buttons = MessageBoxButtons.OK;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtBakPath.Text))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(errorMSG01, captionMSG, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        else if (!Directory.Exists(BackupPath))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(errorMSG02, captionMSG, buttons, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }
        else
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            string sql = null;
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            connetionString = ("Data Source=DPC-OHEINRICH\\NETZWERKLABOR; Integrated Security=True;");
            sql = "Select * from Sys.Databases";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                StatusPrinter(0x0003, null);
                CreateLogfile(BackupPath);
                DeleteOldBakFiles();
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    string db_name = Convert.ToString(dataReader.GetValue(0));
                    Task backupTask = Task.Run(() => BackupProcess(ServerName, SQLinstance, BackupPath, db_name));
                }
                dataReader.Close();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblStatusMessage.Content = Convert.ToString(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void BackupProcess(string ServerName, string SQLinstance, string BackupPath, string db_name)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        string todayformat = string.Format("{0:G}", today);
        string BakFileDate = todayformat.Replace(".", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace(":", "");
        string ReportBakFile = BackupPath + "\\" + db_name + "_db_" + BakFileDate + @".bak'";

        if (db_name != "tempdb")
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlCommand command;
            string sql = null;
            SqlDataReader dataReader;
            connetionString = ("Data Source="+ServerName+"\\"+SQLinstance+"; Integrated Security=True;");
            sql = @"BACKUP DATABASE " + db_name + @" TO DISK = '" + BackupPath + "\\" + db_name + "_db_" + BakFileDate + @".bak'";
            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
                dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                dataReader.Close();
                command.Dispose();
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.WriteLogile(1, ReportBakFile)));
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.StatusPrinter(0x0004, db_name)));
        }
    }
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        //we are done...
    }
```